# Get specific type of objects in a class and change their properties

Tags: python

I have three classes Box, Tab and UI which the first two are being called in the UI. I want to get the box instances (in this case Ghi and Dni) and change their items in a function (as you can see the describtion in the get_boxes() function).

```
class Box():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.status = 'no'

class Tab():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''

class UI():

    def __init__(self):
        self.__setupui()

    def __setupui(self):
        self.Ghi = Box()
        self.Ghi.name = 'Ghi'
        self.Ghi.status = 'yes'

        self.Dni = Box()
        self.Dni.name = 'Dni'

        self.tab = Tab()
        self.tab.name = 'tab1'

    def get_boxes(self):
        # get the Box instances in the UI (such as Ghi and Dni)
        # change their status
        return  # list of Box instances name

ui_sample = UI()
```

How can I define get_boxes() function? or in general how can I loop trough self.**objects** and check their type then change their values inside of a class?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly? What's the use case of the get_boxes()?

Comment: You don't need a loop; you already know the names of the attributes you want to modify.

Comment: @spider I want to return a list of Box names which their status is 'yes', which I found the answer, thanks.

Comment: @chepner yes in this casw, which is a simplified example we know the names, however, with user selected instances we do not all the names that's why in needed to check the type, which I got the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate more on @jnnnnn answer `get_boxes` will look like this:

```
def get_boxes(self):
    return [a for a in self.__dict__ if isinstance(a, Box)]
```

Or even better will be to setup things as follows:

class UI():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.boxes = []
    self.__setupui()


def __setupui(self):
    Ghi = Box()
    Ghi.name = 'Ghi'
    Ghi.status = 'yes'
    self.boxes.append(Ghi)

    Dni = Box()
    Dni.name = 'Dni'
    self.boxes.append(Dni)

    self.tab = Tab()
    self.tab.name = 'tab1'

def get_boxes(self):
    return self.boxes
```

Comment: Thanks,  I used the first one with isinstance and some modification regarding to my problem

Answer (score 2):

I would assign all the items to a list as they are created so it is easy to iterate, like `self.controls` or something.

You can use python's`type` function to get the typename of an object if you only want to perform some actions for some controls in the list.

Otherwise you would probably use `dir(self)` or `self.__dict__` to iterate all the members, and then you would have to do type checking.

Comment: Thanks, I used the self.__dict__ and isinstance